How to print argparse help message when parser is declared in function?
I am using following code, I want to show help message if no argument is used. But when I use parser.print_help() the compiler returns NameError: name 'parser' is not defined. If I use args.print_help() the compiler returns AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'print_help'.
import os,subprocess,argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate a power comparision report.')
    # Define command-line arguments
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='test', help='test1,tes2,...etc')
    return parser.parse_args() 

def main():
    args = parse_args()  
    
    if args.test is None :
        print("\n run will start for all test cases in 3 mins,\n following are the default values, use switches to change them")
        parser.print_help() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  

I am expecting a way to print help message if no argument is provided.

parser is indeed not defined where you're trying to call its print_help method - it's only defined inside parse_args, and the only thing that returns is what you're calling args (and why you thought that would also have a print_help method is totally unclear).

@jonrsharpe I knew parser has a method named print_help() as I have called parse_args() (where parser is initialized)  in main() method, so thought args might have this method, I even tried args.parser.print_help() which also didn't worked

That's what the required parameter is for.

You need to restructure this a bit so that the arg parsing happens where you want to print help. I usually structure things this way:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import argparse

def main(args):
    # Do things with args...
        
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Define command-line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate a power comparison report.')
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='test', help='test1,tes2,...etc')

    # Make sure we have some command line arguments
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        args = parser.parse_args()
        main(args)

A brief explanation:

When the program launches we check our context. If we're runningt the script directly, (__name__ == "__main__" evaluates to True)  we setup our argument parser.
Then we check to see if we have any arguments. If there is only one argument in sys.argv (the first is always the name of the script), then we know that no other arguments have been passed, so we print the help statement to stderr and then exit with an error code.
Otherwise, we parse the command line arguments and pass them along to the main function.


you could change your parse_args function to a setup_parser function and parse the arguments in main:
def setup_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate a power comparison report.')
    # Define command-line arguments
    parser.add_argument('-t', dest='test', help='test1,tes2,...etc')
    return parser


def main():
    parser = setup_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.test is None:
        print("\n run will start for all test cases in 3 mins,\n following are the default values, use switches to change them")
        parser.print_help()


it should be optional, if not provided will run for all test cases, else to only with specified. hence I want to caution the user that run is starting with all test cases if no argument is provided.

@SachinMirajkar sorry that I misunderstood your question, I updated my answer with a simple change to your code that should work
